# HTTP Pipelining support in Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

Is HTTP-Pipelining supported already in Camel HTTP4 component , if yes is it supported by default or any additional configuration is required?

Also, is it possible to send POST requests which are idempotent by design using the same component?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the AHC component -  http://camel.apache.org/ahc.html

Comment: Thank you for the comment, this link talks only about how to use ahc in camel, if possible please provide any link/documentation which provides information on when to use Async Http Client library and why.

Comment: I thought you need to submit several HTTP requests and don't wait for the response. That's what AHC does.